# How can i filter filter custom post types using DateTime Variable

Tags: php, date

I am attempting to filter custom post types using DateTime but seem to be getting an error here is the code tried:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['start_date'])): 
$startdate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', 
$_REQUEST['start_date']);
$start_date=$startdate->format('Y-m-d');
$enddate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $_REQUEST['end_date']);
$end_date=$enddate->format('Y-m-d');
```

it returns a fatal error on

```
 $startdate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y')
```

Comment: Can you check that the date your getting in `$_REQUEST['start_date']` is of format `'d/m/Y'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite to:

```
   $startdate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $_REQUEST['start_date']);
   if ($startdate) {
       $start_date = $startdate->format('Y-m-d');
   } else {
       // wrong date format in request -> handle error
   }
```

(Modified to only keep the error handling and not the comment about the initial if statement block)

Comment: I'm assuming they are using the [alternative if](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) construct as they have a `:` at the end of the first line.

Comment: yeah... possibly the endif; was behind the code block. Looks a bit messy without indentation. -- removed the initial if statement comment to only keep the error handling if block

Comment: thanks, guys this is still not getting the result ill to have to look at this from scratch